# Cannot match navigation case in JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I want to rewrite this http address using JSF tag:

```
<a href="/module1/page/UserNavigation.html" class="dir">Home</a>
```

Into this:

```
<h:link value="HOME" class="dir" outcome="/module1/page/UserNavigation.xhtml" />
```

But when I test the page I get warning message `Cannot match navigation case`. That's because the address is pointing outside the module but it's correct.

Can I suppress that warning somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<h:link>` tag is used to generate plain anchor elements for *JSF navigation cases only*, by referring to a *navigation case outcome* in its `outcome` attribute, and is not intended to (can't) be used to navigate to any other resouces, even be them within the same web applcation, for which there is `<h:outputLink>` tag.

So, a navigation case in your example should be `/module1/page/UserNavigation`. On the other hand, you could change the tag to `<h:outputLink>` and change `outcome` for `value` attribute and it'll work smoothly.